# How to register a new user in ASP.NET MVC application by passing the data into a Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application, I want to make the Admin User add a new user. Upon signing in, the registration form fields (registration view) with new user values are captured in `AccountController` of the ASP.NET MVC 5 application as follows, and which then calls the API and the data must be transferred there:

```
[HttpPost]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(AccountRegistration register)
{
        string baseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseUrl"];

        //var client = new HttpClient();
        //client.BaseAddress = new Uri("api/Account/Register");
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        string accessToken = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["auth_key"].Values["token"];

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {                
            var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "firstname", register.FirstName.Trim()},
                { "lastname", register.LastName.Trim()},
                { "email", register.Email.Trim()},
                { "phone", register.PhoneNo.Trim()},
                { "password", register.Password.Trim()},
            };

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

            var res = client.PostAsync(baseAddress + "/api/Account/Register", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(register), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            res.Wait();
            var taskResponse = res.Result;

            var data = taskResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>(new[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() }).Result;

        }

        return View();
}
```

Here is my Web API `AccountController` code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Register([FromBody]UserRegister register)
{
        DBAccess dblayer = new DBAccess();

        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            UserManager<IdentityUser> _manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new TachusApi.DBContext.AuthDbContext()));
            string pHash = _manager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(register.Password);

            dblayer.SaveAdmin(register, pHash);
            return Ok("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Ok("Something went wrong.");
        }
}
```

And here is the `DBAccess.cs` method which is called from this API's Register method to actually save the data into the database.

```
#region Save Admin

    public void SaveAdmin(UserRegister user, string passwordHash)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlCommand command = null;
        int retValue;

        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "Sp_Add_Admin";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", user.Email);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PasswordHash", passwordHash);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", user.FirstName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", user.LastName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", user.PhoneNumber);

        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

    }

    #endregion
```

My problem is that I have all the values of Register.cshtml (User Registration View) available on both the Register and SaveAdmin methods of the API except the phone number. I think I have some ambiguity in the model classes that I have created. I want the data to be stored in the database using a stored procedure I created.

When I run the code and the API is called, I am getting exception. Is there any one who can suggest me the best way to manage my code so that I can save the data into the database?

Comment: WHAT exception?  That's incredibly relevant information

Comment: @JohnLord I am getting null reference exception or {"A task was canceled."}

Comment: post the stack trace if you have it.  We create users like this at work with a custom function so i may be able to help.